# How to run php when an option is selected from a select list?

Tags: php, html

I would like to have a select list that runs a php database query when an option is selected. I have the code:

```
<select>
  <option value="available">Available</option>
  <option value="sold">Sold</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="change status">
```

Say, when a user selects 'sold' I would like to run:

```
<?php 
  db_query("UPDATE {product_stock} SET stock='0' WHERE nid='$value'");  
?>
```

I've tried

```
<option value="sold" <?php db_query("UPDATE {product_stock} SET stock='0' WHERE nid='$value'");  ?> >Sold</option>
```

but doesn't seem to work. 
I don't know if I should be using

```
<form method="GET">...</form>
```

I know I can use `ajax` somehow but I'm really not familiar with it.
Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to use javascript! Or else you must update your database after form submit.

A possible way with *the javascript library jquery* would be:

```
$("select").change(function() {
   $.post("/your/url", {option: $(this).val()}, function(return) {
      //echo result if necessary
   }
});
```

On server side you should check for `$_POST['option']` and update your database after you

> ESCAPED

the contents of the variable "option".

Comment: That's not only JavaScript but a use of jQuery library. You should point it somewhere.

Comment: I'm new to jquery I don't understand where to put the HTML for the select options and where to write my database query. Could you write a more detailed answer and include the HTML and PHP. Also what do you mean ESCAPED?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send an AJAX call with jquery or plain JavaScript when the combobox got changed.
Depending on the new value, you can send various parameter and call your PHP scripts.

But the interaction between HTML and PHP like you tried will never work. The time you see the combo box in your browser, your PHP commands were already executed.

Answer (score 0):

My site is build on drupal so I created a custom module and used hook_form_alter so I could just use PHP and didn't need to code in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to create two files one with the form and a second one with the action itself, the first will have something like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="ActionFile.php">
    <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="find name">
</form>
```

and create a file called ActionFile.php that will contain the variables and the connection to the DB and the select.